# kaching-php Shopping Cart Plugin configuration issues with CakePHP2.0

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, shopping-cart, cart

I did the following steps to configure the kaching-php Shopping Cart Plugin in my cakephp2.0.Placed the plugin in app/plugin folder and import the database.After that Replace the data in app/config/routes.php to

```
<?php
include (APP . ‘plugins’ . DS . ‘kaching’ . DS . ‘config’ . DS . ‘routes.php’);
Router::connect(‘/’, array(‘plugin’=>’kaching’, ‘controller’ => ‘carts’, ‘action’ => ‘category’, ‘1’));
?>
```

After these configuration i got this error failed to open stream: No such file or directory Then i changed the above code to

```
include (APP . 'Plugin' . DS . 'kaching' . DS . 'config' . DS . 'routes.php');
Router::connect('/', array('Plugin'=>'kaching', 'controller' => 'carts', 'action' => 'category', '1'));
```

Now I am getting this error Error: CartsController could not be found.

Please let me know can we use these plugin with cakephp2.0 or is there any other shopping cart plugin which we can integrate with our cakephp2.0 site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is "plugin" not "Plugin", array keys are case sensitive

Try :

```
include (APP . 'Plugin' . DS . 'kaching' . DS . 'config' . DS . 'routes.php');
Router::connect('/', array('plugin'=>'kaching', 'controller' => 'carts', 'action' => 'category', '1'));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: As you have mentioned i have changed the code to :include (APP . 'Plugin' . DS . 'kaching' . DS . 'config' . DS . 'routes.php');
 Router::connect('/', array('plugin'=>'kaching', 'controller' => 'carts', 'action' => 'category', '1')); but still its not working now  am getting error: Fatal Error (256): [MissingPluginException] Plugin Kaching could not be found. Note : I am using cakephp2.0 and new to cake .Thanks for your valuable time and for help.

Comment: The message error is clear : check that you have the "Kaching" folder in your "Plugin" folder, and it is case-sensitive too... Good luck

Comment: my plugin name is kaching in error its finding for  Kaching (Capital K).Everything is fine kaching is inside the app/Plugin folder.I am not getting why its not finding the plugin.These are the errors :Fatal Error (256): [MissingPluginException] Plugin Kaching could not be found.
#0 E:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp2sent\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(364): CakePlugin::path('Kaching')
#1 E:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp2sent\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(225): App::pluginPath('Kaching')
#2 E:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp2sent\lib\Cake\View\View.php(1093): App::path('View', 'Kaching')

Comment: just rename the folder 'kaching' to 'Kaching', this is important for deployment even though you still are on windows. It must be here : `E:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp2sent\app\Plugin\Kaching`

Comment: Justin thanks for your help i tried but its not working.Again getting same errors...